# Looking for an offline XML Schema validation tool

Tags: xml, xml-schema-validation

Well, the title is the question. I want to validate XML files against an XML Schema, and I need a tool for that purpose. In fact I have multiple .xsd files, therefore online tools won't really work.

Operating system: Anything Unix, OS X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote one in Java for my own use - Java has XML parsing libraries that validate against XSD.

However, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124865/xml-schema-xsd-validation-tool

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) may be suitable, It may well be already present in a Linux system.

Comment: Oh, thanks - sorry for the duplicate question. `xmllint` is there and it does the job quite well.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Unfortuatnely xmllint doesn't seem to support XML 1.1 - is this correct?

Comment: @David: It seems not, perhaps because [*"In practice we (W3C) have removed most of the need for XML 1.1 by releasing XML 1.0 5e. The correct claim is that XML 1.1 should not be used except where necessary."*](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2010-July/msg00020.html)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Interesting. I had read that 1.1 was supposed to enable unordered extensions (in 1.0 an extension of a type must only use 'sequence', 'all' is not allowed). That is the only reason I was going to try to use 1.1.